# Mod_Rewrite assistance for a noob please

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all URLs of the form:

```
http://www.site.com/push20/dir1/dir2/afile.html
```

to

```
http://www.site.com/dir1/dir2/afile.html
```

I.e. lose the `push20` bit

I've tried with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^push20/(.*) /$1 [R]
```

but its not happening.

Any suggestion?

Comment: suggest you change the question title to be more specific - it will make this a more valuable question to have in the archive. e.g. "How to define a rewrite rule with mod_rewrite"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't you need a leading `/` before `push20`?

i.e:

```
RewriteRule ^/push20/(.*) /$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you can do this with a standard [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive, something along these lines:

```
Redirect /push20 /
```

That should redirect **everything** under /push20 to the root of your site -- basically it strips out push20 and redirects.